# Better word to mean "unintended mix of expressions"

Tags: word-request

I found this sentence in some text:

> The conversation you cite with A, B and C **sounds to my eyes** uncommon.

Based on this, I wanted to explain something like this:

> Most likely, it is a (<strike>contraption</strike>) of *"**sounds** to me"* and *"**to my eyes**"*...

**What is the proper word, instead of <strike>contraption</strike>, which means "unintended mix" or similar?**

Answer (score 1):

There's no word which specifically means an accidental mix of two common phrases. However, the most suitable substitute for the above sentence is:

> It's a **conflation** of "sounds to me" and "to my eyes"

To conflate things means to accidentally merge them.

You could also consider these less suitable alternatives:

- A portmanteau is an intentional combination of two words
- A spoonerism is an accidental swap of syllables/letters
- A convolution is the result of combining two things in a way that the result is twisted together